# Do I need to call CGContextSaveGState and CGContextRestoreGState?

Tags: ios, quartz-graphics

Double checking if I need to call CGContextSaveGState and CGContextRestoreGState even when creating a new imageContext.

From what I've read in the Quartz Programming Guide, I shouldn't need to in the example below, because the I'm creating a brand new image context.

I've searched github for UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions and some folks save and restore the context and other folks do not.

```
// Uses a circularMask on an image
class func circularImage(image: UIImage, diameter: Int) -> UIImage {
    assert(diameter > 0, "Diameter > 0 Failed \(__FUNCTION__)")

    let frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: Double(diameter), height: Double(diameter))
    var newImage: UIImage?

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)

    var context: CGContextRef = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSaveGState(context)

    let imagePath: UIBezierPath = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: frame)
    imagePath.addClip()

    image.drawInRect(frame)

    newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

    return newImage!
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you're right you don't need to save the context state for what you're doing there (and you could safely comment out the ones you have). But if you wanted to 'undo' the clipping you did (for example) then it's a way to do that.  Be careful to always keep these (save/restore)gstate in matching pairs, it's a stack, so you must keep track of anything you put on there.